# Ionic 2 rc1 - Google maps is not visible anymore

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

I'm developing a simple app with google maps and I update ionic version from RC0 to RC1. 
After this update, (google) maps is not visible anymore.

I use a cordoba-plugins-googlemaps and google key is correct and enabled.

I'd like to be more accurate, but I do not know where to look for the problem (I checked ionic consolelogs and log, with catlog, on my android  smartphone).

Someone else has had the same problem and solved it?

### Regards

matpil

Comment: Hi,
Ifind in catlog  this error:
"can not execute resizeMap because the map is not created"

and also:
"asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources"

but online I've found nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Problem is not google maps but ion-card.
Seems that a "google maps" insert into a  doesn't works.

I had removed ioc-card and maps works fine.

Hope this can be useful...

### Regards

matpil